# With SpaceX running multiple launch sites, how are their launch teams structured?

Tags: launch, spacex, falcon-9, launch-site

SpaceX has several launch sites (and landing sites!)

In Florida they started at LC-40, and are working to activate LC-39A for launches, and LC-13 has been re-labelled LZ-1 for landings.

In California, they have SLC-4E for launch and SLC-4W for landings.

Boca Chica, Texas has seen little direct work yet, with the report being they will work on it post-LC-39A activation.

I will ignore Omelek (Falcon-1 launch site in the Kwajellin Atoll) since it is no longer in use.

One of the cost drivers on the space shuttle program was a standing army of staff, paid, regardless of flight rate that had to be maintained. SLS is likely replicating the jobs program aspects of this, for one launch every 3-4 years. SpaceX being dedicated to lower costs is clearly looking to minimize the standing army problem.

How has SpaceX structured their launch site teams?

LC-40 is clearly where most of the staff has been, since there has only been a single Vandenberg flight (Cassioppe) as I write this. However SLC-4 is due to get busier as there are a number of flights on the 2016-2017 manifest set.

When they launch from SLC-4 do they reuse the team from LC-40? Is it a separate team? What is the plan for LC-39A? Share the LC-40 team or have its own dedicated team? The structure of the launch team seems like it would be an interesting thing to understand.

The answer might include it, but a possible secondary question might be, how is their mission control team structured?  One team to rule them all?  Red team/Blue team?  Or a problem to be solved when they have enough missions that they need more staff?

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, as the middle of 2016 passes, it was noted that they have at least two complete launch teams. It was mentioned in the context of Vandenberg vs Florida, as the end of 2016 has several SLC-4E launches scheduled (Iridium Next F1, Sherpa/FormosaSat, and Iridium Next F2).